# VB6 dll in COM+ Sub Main is not called

Tags: dll, com, vb6, windows-server-2012, com+

VB6 dll named SimpleBO with a module (.bas) and `Sub Main` has the following code

```vb
Public gsConnectionString As String

Sub Main()
    Dim constr As String
    constr = getConStr() 'get it from a file
    gsConnectionString = constr
    LogToFile "At main after getting constr showing gsConnectionString " & gsConnectionString 'logToFile simply writes a line in a file
    ....
    Exit Sub
    ... Error handler
Exit sub
```

The module also has a public method:

```vb
Public Function GetConnectionEnterprise() As String
   GetConnectionEnterprise = gsConnectionString
Exit Function
```

The dll has a class called `SystemBO` with different methods including:

```vb
Public Function Connection() As String
    Connection = GetConnectionEnterprise
Exit Function
```

Then a VB6 exe also has a module with `Sub Main` as it startup.
It references the dll and has this code in the sub main:

```vb
Public gsConnectionString as String

Sub Main()
    Dim oBO As SimpleBO.SystemBO
    Set oBO = New SimpleBO.SystemBO
    gsConnectionString = oBO.Connection
    LogToFile "InTestBOSimple:ModStartUpForTestBOSimple:Main gsConnectionString " & gsConnectionString
    frmTestBO1.Show
    Set oBO = Nothing
    Exit Sub
```

The VB6 is added as a COM+ component.

First test on a Windows 10 computer - running the exe.

The log file shows:

```
SimpleBO:modStartUp:Main At main after getting constr showing gsConnectionString Provider=sqlOLEDB;Data ...
```

Then

```
InTestBOSimple:ModStartUpForTestBOSimple:Main gsConnectionString Provider=sqlOLEDB;Data Source
```

Results as expected. The `Sub Main` of the dll is called.

Next install the dll and the exe on Windows Server 2012 running on a VM.

The dll is installed in Com+ with same setup.

Then when running the exe (which runs with no errors) the log file does not show that the `Sub Main` of the dll was called and only shows:

```
InTestBOSimple:ModStartUpForTestBOSimple:Main gsConnectionString (blank)
```

Meaning the call to `oBO.Connection`, which did not error out, returned nothing, which also shows that `Sub Main` of the dll was not called.

I tried various things - re install the com+ from scratch on the server but same issues.

I tried to add code in the exe which has a form and on a button click has

```vb
Private Sub cmdGetCN_Click()
    Dim oBO As SimpleBO.SystemBO
    Dim cn As String
    Set oBO = New SimpleBO.SystemBO
    cn = oBO.Connection
    lblMessage.Caption = "cn = " & cn
    Exit Sub
```

the message showed `CN =` (and blank after it).

Did anyone experience this type of issue?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the issue is that it doesn't run, rather than that it runs and fails before it has a chance to log?

Comment: I will look into again to see if it gets to the Error handler of Sub Main.

Comment: Asking the trivial question sometimes helps :-)

Comment: How did I miss it? too many iterations and missing an obvious option. Of course Sub Main should always be called. Yes, there was an error just before the LogToFile coming from another call to a function that I didn't show in my code about "permission denied" which makes more sense when running on a server.  This I can figure out.